# Generate full folder structure (topfolders, subfolders, subsubfolder, etc) via excel

Tags: vba, excel, directory-structure

I have searched all over and tried a lot of different VBA code - no luck so far.

**Problem:**

Extremely long list of "folders to be created" written in Excel. All folders and subfolder names are listed in the same column in subsequent rows. Another column defines if it is a subfolder or not. Like this

```
Folder name      Folder level
A                1
B                1
C                2
D                3
E                3
F                2
G                3
H                4
```

**Solution:**

Code that can either (preferable) create the folder structure based on the existing numbering or (alternative) code that can create the folder structure based on columns, i.e. I can move the folder names around so that all sub folders are in column B, subsubfolders in column C, etc. I would prefer be able to leave cells empty so that I do not have repeat the names of all topfolders. I.e. I would prefer (for the alternative solution) to be able use something like this:

```
Folder Level 1   Folder level 2   Folder Level 3  Folder Level 4
A
B                
                 C
                              D                
                                  E                
                 F                
                                  G
                                                   H
```

I do hope that some of you can help. I am very new to VBA so doing the coding myself is out of the question.

Comment: Ups I can see that the layout of my examples are all messed up. Please disregard them. Sadly I am not allowed to post pictures.

Comment: `I am very new to VBA so doing the coding myself is out of the question.` Stackoverflow is not a coding website. I would recommend learning VBA and then asking a question. If this is something that you need urgently then consider hiring someone on sites like freelancer.com/elance.com :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. From browsing around on this and other fora, I can see that even though I should learn VBA, I would not be there. It seems that most users answering questions similar to mine, only knows how to make directories with one level or only with one subfolder in each folder. Thus even though I should use a lot of time learning VBA, I would probably still have the same issues: I.e. 1. how to i create a directory that has a lot of different subfolders, and often more than one. 2. how do I do it when my basis is a list of folder names and not a full folder path.

Answer (score 0):

The data provided does not provide clear definition as to what is needed. (ie. What sub-folders belong to what parent folders) The best advice I can give you at this time  is to research the `MkDir()` function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1d22wfh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Keep in mind that this function can not build an entire directory structure at once, it can only add a single directory to an existing one, one level at a time.

This being said, your task would be much easier if you were provided data in the format of:

```
C:\Parent Folder 1\Sub Folder 1\Sub Sub Folder 1
C:\Parent Folder 2
C:\Parent Folder 3\Sub Folder 3
```

Then your task would be to sparse the final directory and build it one level at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply - much appreciated!

Yes it would be so much easier. However I have been provided (and will often in times to come, be provided) roughly 400 entirely different folder names listed like the first example above.

I apologise for not being clear as to which parent folders the individual subfolders belong to. I should have stated that above listing is based on a very simple principle: You read the hierachy from top to bottom, resulting in a folder always being a subfolder to the folder above unless they are at the same level (then they will be "sister-folders").

Comment: In the examples above that results in the following: Folder A doesn't have any subfolders. Folder B has two subfolders (C and F). D and E are subfolders to C, while G is a subfolder to F. G has H as a subfolder.
Even though I get all the folder names in one column, I can quite easily move them around like this. Thats why I was hoping for a solution this way.

Comment: And sorry for not thanking you for the link. I will definitely read up on it. I do however think that it will prove difficult for me to solve the issue by myself.